Combine tool returns a large attribute table
The Crux of the problem is my attribute table being too large. I need a way to combine rows of a raster to preserve some values and erase/change others.
What started this problem, however, was likely in the methods. I needed to separate a raster to run a "maximum likelihood classification" so I could run the classification on smaller areas. So, I need to separate a raster into three raster layers, run a classification, then merge the three raster layers back together.
To separate, I created polygons (by using the "split" tool on the large polygon of the area) to clip the raster but found this created gaps when I "clip raster". Instead, I changed the polygons into rasters ("polygon to raster") then "extract by attributes" to get each section to clip by. I used "extract by mask" to separate the large raster. I can't remember if I exported the files but then I ran the classification on each piece.
After classification, I have three attribute tables shown below. I have exported these layers so they have tiffs now. The cell sizes match and they are on the same coordinate systems. If I try to mosaic them, the attributes combine, meaning the "lakesurface" of the first attribute table will combine with "wetland" of the other two attribute tables.



Instead, I tried to combine them ("combine" tool), which was a semi-success. Now I have a massive attribute table, as shown below. As far as I understand, the -123 is the value found in an area around the clipped raster and 0 is the area even further away from the area. Basically, -123 and 0 are like odd buffer zones around the actual values, of which I only want one. So, instead of getting 1,0,0; I'm getting 1,0,-123; 1,-123,0; 1,0,0; 1,-123,-123, etc combos. I want to change the chart so I'm getting just 1,0,0; 0,1,0; 0,2,0; 0,3,0; etc.

